# Type checking in arrays

Tags: typescript

I have a class

`class Clazz{constructor(public foo: string, public bar: string)}`

and then I am creating an array like this:

```
var cls: Clazz[] = [{foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar'}, {foo:'Missing bar'}]
```

The type checker does not complain about the item with missing `bar`. Is this by design? If yes, what is the motivation behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The type checker does not complain about the item with missing bar

It does:

[image]

See the sample in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Clazz%7Bconstructor(public%20foo%3A%20string%2C%20public%20bar%3A%20string)%7B%7D%7D%0A%0Avar%20cls%3A%20Clazz%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%7Bfoo%3A%20'Foo'%2C%20bar%3A%20'Bar'%7D%2C%20%7Bfoo%3A'Missing%20bar'%7D%5D).

Note that your code also had a syntax error (which was also reported ... the constructor body was missing).

Comment: it seems to be an issue of my IDE (IntelliJ Idea), checked on VS Code and works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out arguments and they will be initialized with their default value. This usually is done if you don't know the desired value yet or you are fine with the default value being set. Additionally, if you have a class with a lot of properties, you might not want to set them all in the constructor call.

Comment: When I try to create a single instance, e.g. var c: Clazz = {foo: 'Missing bar'}, then the type checker complains - my class has no default values set. In my example, the second item does not have the structural type compatible with 'Clazz', thus it would be unusable in a context, where a  'Clazz' is expected.